# Delete all rows based on last online time?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How would I go about deleting all "users"/rows from my table called:

```
users
```

Here is a screenshot of the structure: http://i.gyazo.com/d2a06e82f10cc52b6acfb4844caa097e.png

I would like to delete all members that haven't been online for the last 6 months: http://i.gyazo.com/8226d1f9a89c13de09ed94db0dabf174.png

Could someone help me with the code please?

Comment: You should put the table format in the question.

Comment: Sorry I am not experienced when it comes to mysql, what do you mean by table format?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it is something like this:

```
delete users
    where online <= now() - interval 6 month;
```

Comment: Can that be executed directly from phpmyadmin?